# How to identify which .pyd files are required for the execution of exe files generated using py2exe module

Tags: python, pydev, py2exe, python-imaging-library, pyd

I have written a python script and generated an exe using py2exe on Windows 32 bit OS. While I'm trying to execute the generated exe file, I'm getting the below error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program01.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PIL\Image.pyc", line 67, in <module>
  File "PIL\_imaging.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "PIL\_imaging.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

---

Is there any way to identify the complete list what .pyd files are required for my program to be executed.

Below is my program import statements.

```
from __future__ import division
import os, sys, math, aggdraw
from PIL import Image
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree as LETREE
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include modules by adding `options` argument into `setup`:

```
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, "includes" : ['os', 'sys', 'math', 'aggdraw', 'PIL', 'xml.etree.ElementTree', 'lxml.etree' ]}
   }
```

Only thing that could be different in code above is that you might need to replace `xml.etree.ElementTree` with `xml` and `lxml.etree` with `lxml` as I'm not quite sure about those.